# How to block a Venmo user?

Tags: venmo

A user who doesn't owe me money is repeatedly sending me money on Venmo.  How can I block them?

For some background, this is occurring to a friend of mine after a breakup, and neither he nor I have been able to find a way to block someone.

Comment: Isn't that free money?

Comment: @EightDaysofMalaise yeah that's my attitude.

Comment: @Pnuts no that is just how I phrased the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partially in response to my badgering of Venmo, they've added the ability to block users:

https://help.venmo.com/hc/en-us/articles/222478088-Blocking-Another-User

```
Here’s how:

1. Log in to the Venmo app on your iPhone or Android device
2. Tap the "☰" icon in the upper left hand corner of the app
3. Tap “Search People” to find the user that you want to block
4. Once you’re on their profile page, tap the three circles in the upper right corner of the screen
5. You should see an option to block the user in red
```